# How to convert Object[] to java class

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

Is there a way to cast an Object array into a java class?,

Example: I have a class "Person" with the next attributes: Name, age, address. And i have an Object[] with this: [1]: "Peter", [2]: 20, [3]: "California 130".
I want to do something like this:

```
Person p =  new Person();
Object[] o = new Object[2];
p = (Person) o;
```

I have to do this without set the values one by one, example:

```
p.setName((String)o[0]);
```

Is there a way?

Regards

Comment: Is there a way to do this? No

Comment: Whatever problem you're trying to solve by doing this, there's a better way to solve it.

Comment: You could make a method that takes an ```Object[]``` and returns a ```Person```, but why use an ```Object[]``` in the first place?

Comment: Performing class casts like this is going to give you ClassCastException pretty much always. Instead, you probably want to have methods in Person that can e.g. set the person's name (`Person#setName(String)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to have the compiler convert an array of Object automagically into a a class with fields, and this just isn't possible. Instead you *could* create a constructor that takes an array of object and then assigns each item in the array into the fields of your class, but while this can be done, it has a bad code smell. Better to avoid use of Object arrays entirely, that is, arrays that hold items of different types. Instead deal with fields and parameters that have appropriate and actual types, and pass correctly typed items into your class's constructor. i.e.,

```
public Person(String name, int age, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
Person convert(Object[] o){
    String name = (String) o[0];
    int age = (int) o[1];
    String address = (String) o[2];
    Person p = new Person(name, age, address);
    return p;
}
```

this method asks for this Object[] and returns a person with the information.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it, as this would cause `ClassCastException` to be thrown. The reason is that because of inheritance and the is-a relationship.

Every `Person` object is an `Object` and every `String` object is of type `Object`. However, the opposite is not true. This is like saying every horse is a mammal, but not every mammal is a horse.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in the person class (setAttributes(Object[])for example) that sets the person attributes from the array values.